# iOS - When starting a recording, the bluetooth device thinks I'm making a phone call

Tags: ios, bluetooth, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I have a recording app. I'm running into a problem that when I open my app and the phone is paired to a bluetooth device, as soon as I start recording, the bluetooth device thinks I'm starting a phone call. It makes an outgoing call sound, and displays on the screen "ON CALL" (always talking about the BT device), but no actual call is being made of course.

This is how I'm currently initializing my session:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone
                                                   error:nil];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                 withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers | 
                                             AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth
                                       error: nil];
```

I tried it on 2 different bluetooth devices and similar outcomes happen on the same. Both try to establish a phone call.

After looking at BlueTooth logs, I found some clue as to what it is doing:

```
12:24:07.185 A2DPClient.cpp:390        StopStreaming        A2DP       Notice     Stopping A2DP audio streaming
12:24:07.186 A2DPClient.cpp:415        StopStreaming        A2DP       Notice     Sending 'A2DP audio disconnected' event for device 00:19:B5:FE:05:9B "VW_RADIO_55"
12:24:07.201 HandsfreeAudioPlugIn.cpp:971 audioDataAvailable   Handsfree  Notice     HandsfreeAudioPlugIn:: Audio available event for 00:19:B5:FE:05:9B, reason: 2
12:24:07.203 HandsfreeAudioPlugIn.cpp:971 audioDataAvailable   Handsfree  Notice     HandsfreeAudioPlugIn:: Audio available event for 00:19:B5:FE:05:9B, reason: 4
12:24:07.203 HandsfreeAudioPlugIn.cpp:971 audioDataAvailable   Handsfree  Notice     HandsfreeAudioPlugIn:: Audio available event for 00:19:B5:FE:05:9B, reason: 1
12:24:07.203 HandsfreeGateway.cpp:699  createVisualVoicemai Handsfree  Notice     Setting up virtual call
12:24:07.205 AudioSendThread.cpp:91    run                  Audio      Notice     AudioSendThread stopping
12:24:07.207 HandsfreeGateway.cpp:1540 initiateScoConnectio Handsfree  Notice     Initiating SCO connection with delay of 20 milliseconds
12:24:07.207 HandsfreeGateway.cpp:3179 handleUpdateCallStat Handsfree  Notice     Updating call status for call(s): [ [#1: Outgoing to +XXXXXXXXXXXXX "My Number" (voicemail)] ]
12:24:07.207 HandsfreeGateway.cpp:1523 delayScoConnection   Handsfree  Notice     Delaying SCO connection by 20 milliseconds
12:24:07.208 HandsfreeGateway.cpp:3183 handleUpdateCallStat Handsfree  Notice     callPresent: no, callState: 1, callSetup: outgoing, heldStatus: none, heldChanged: no, visualVoicemail: yes
12:24:07.208 HandsfreeGateway.cpp:2871 tellEveryOneAboutVVM Handsfree  Notice     Sending call setup "outgoing" to device 00:19:B5:FE:05:9B "VW_RADIO_55"
12:24:07.208 HandsfreeGateway.cpp:2877 tellEveryOneAboutVVM Handsfree  Notice     Sending call status "call active" to device 00:19:B5:FE:05:9B "VW_RADIO_55"
12:24:07.208 HandsfreeGateway.cpp:2760 operator()           Handsfree  Notice     Sending call setup "none" to device 00:19:B5:FE:05:9B "VW_RADIO_55"
12:24:07.229 HandsfreeGateway.cpp:1626 internalConnectAudio Handsfree  Notice     Making outgoing audio connection to device 00:19:B5:FE:05:9B "VW_RADIO_55"
12:24:07.457 HandsfreeGateway.cpp:1161 audioEvent           Handsfree  Notice     Received audio connected event for device 00:19:B5:FE:05:9B "VW_RADIO_55"
12:24:07.471 A2DPClient.cpp:1384       SuspendCfm           A2DP       Notice     Successfully suspended stream to device 00:19:B5:FE:05:9B "VW_RADIO_55"
12:25:36.959 LeObserver.cpp:904        scanTimer            Discovery  Notice     Session "wirelessproxd-central-35-1" is now at scan level 3
12:25:59.599 HandsfreeAudioPlugIn.cpp:1050 audioPauseNotificati Handsfree  Notice     HandsfreeGateway::audioPauseNotification
12:25:59.599 HandsfreeGateway.cpp:726  deleteVisualVoicemai Handsfree  Notice     Cleaning up virtual call
12:25:59.599 HandsfreeGateway.cpp:1567 internalDisconnectAu Handsfree  Notice     Disconnecting audio from device 00:19:B5:FE:05:9B "VW_RADIO_55"
```

What is that Setting up virtual call??? The only thing I'm doing in code at that point is

```
[self.audioRecorder record];
```

`self.audioRecorder` is an instance of `AVAudioRecorder` of course.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Change your `AVAudioSession` options whenever you want to start recording and do not allow Bluetooth:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] overrideOutputAudioPort:AVAudioSessionPortOverrideNone
                                                   error:nil];

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord
                                 withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers
                                       error: nil];

[self.audioRecorder record];
```

Once finished the recording, on the delegate call of the `AVAudioRecorder` instance:

`- (void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder successfully:(BOOL)flag`

Set up back your `AVAudioSession` options to allow Bluetooth `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth` this way the `AVAudioSession` will not assume the recording input should be handled as Voice Call from the connected BT device.

Comment: But won't this disconnect my current playback from the bluetooth device if there is one?

Comment: yeap ... it's not ideal, but you could also store the position of your current playback and resume it after setCategory. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/HandlingAudioInterruptions/HandlingAudioInterruptions.html

Comment: Yeah, this wouldn't work for me. It's a karaoke application, so I need the playback to continue WHILE recording. Thanks for the suggestion anyway.